# Angular 2 - Error on attribute directive syntax..has i missed anything?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, angularjs-directive

My Error:

```
ERROR in C:/smartphoneSalesApp/src/app/test.directive.ts (9,3): Declaration expe
cted.

ERROR in C:/smartphoneSalesApp/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts (7,3): A
rgument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives: typeof tes
tDirective[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not ex
ist in type 'Component'.
```

My component code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { testDirective } from '../test.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  directives: [testDirective]
})

export class DashboardComponent {
  title = 'Welcome to Dashboard';
}
```

i dono why i'm getting this error. do i need to import any angular core module which related to the directive..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. directives property is no longer supported in the `@Component` decorator so you just need to register the directive in the `@NgModule`
2. you have an extra semicolon here:

`@Directive({se... 'onMouseLeave()'}}); <----`

Comment: declarations: [ AppComponent, DashboardComponent, SmartphoneListComponent, AddSmartphoneComponent, SmartphoneComponent, sortSmartphonePipe, testDirective, TestComponentComponent ], I have already added it.

Comment: @PalzPal, that's fine, just remove it from component then

Comment: yes removed then
ERROR in C:/smartphoneSalesApp/src/app/test.directive.ts (9,3): Declaration expe
cted.

Comment: show the code for test directive

Comment: import { Directive, ElementRef, Host } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[boldHover]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave()'
  }
});

export class testDirective {
  private element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(element: ElementRef){
    this.element = element.nativeElement;
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    this.element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.element.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  }
}

Comment: remove the semicolon after `@Directive({se... 'onMouseLeave()'}}); <----`

Comment: it's working..!! :)

Comment: @PalzPal, glad I could help. Consider accepting my answer then)